# JTable - cell content disappears on double click

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a problem with a JTable.  When I'm typing in a cell with a fixed-length textfield as editor, I'm automatically jumping to the next row when the length is reached.  In that way, I can keep writing.  Afterwards, when I want to change some text in the first row and I double click on the cell, the text disappears.

The strange thing is that when I press "Enter" to go to the next line and I double click on the first line, the text doesn't disappear.

```
private void initialize() {

    vCommentaarHeaders.add(resourceBundle.getString("col_Aan"));
    vCommentaarHeaders.add(resourceBundle.getString("Commentaar"));

    tmCommentaar.addTableModelListener(new CommentaarTableModelListener());

    jtable = new JTable(tmCommentaar);

    //...

    jtable.addMouseListener(new CommentaarTableMouseListener());
    jtable.addKeyListener(new CommentaarTableKeyListener());

    //fill combobox
    //Get saved data
    //Add empty line

    jtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(
            new DefaultCellEditor(cbxAan));
    jtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(
            new DefaultCellEditor(ftfCommentaar));

    //Add table to content pane

}

// MouseListener ....

private class CommentaarTableKeyListener implements KeyListener {

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (selectedColumn != jtable.getSelectedColumn()
                || selectedRow != jtable.getSelectedRow()) {
            sCommentaar = (String) ((Vector) vCommentaarData.get(jtable
                    .getSelectedRow())).get(1);
        }

        if (e.getKeyChar() != '\t' || e.getKeyChar() != '\n') {
            if (e.getKeyChar() == '') {
                sCommentaar = sCommentaar.substring(0,
                        sCommentaar.length() - 1);
                selectedColumn = jtable.getSelectedColumn();
                selectedRow = jtable.getSelectedRow();
            } else {
                if (sCommentaar.length() <= 65){
                    sCommentaar = sCommentaar + e.getKeyChar();
                    selectedColumn = jtable.getSelectedColumn();
                    selectedRow = jtable.getSelectedRow();
                }
                else{
                    //addEmptyLine();
                    tmCommentaar.setValueAt(sCommentaar, selectedRow, selectedColumn);
                    selectedColumn = jtable.getSelectedColumn();
                    selectedRow = jtable.getSelectedRow() + 1;
                    String sBestemmeling = (String) ((Vector) vCommentaarData.get(selectedRow-1)).get(0);
                    Vector vHulp = new Vector();
                    vHulp.add(sBestemmeling);
                    vHulp.add("" + e.getKeyChar());
                    sCommentaar = "" + e.getKeyChar();
                    if( vCommentaarData.size() >= selectedRow )
                        vCommentaarData.setSize(selectedRow + 1);
                    vCommentaarData.setElementAt(vHulp, selectedRow);

                    tmCommentaar.fireTableDataChanged();

                    jtable.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

                    jtable.getCellEditor(selectedRow - 1, selectedColumn).cancelCellEditing();
                    jtable.changeSelection(selectedRow, selectedColumn, false, false);
                    jtable.grabFocus();

                }

            }

        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            if(selectedRow > 0){
                String sBestemmeling = (String) ((Vector) vCommentaarData.get(selectedRow-1)).get(0);
                Vector vHulp = new Vector();
                vHulp.add(sBestemmeling);
                vHulp.add("");
                if( vCommentaarData.size() >= selectedRow )
                    vCommentaarData.setSize(selectedRow + 1);
                vCommentaarData.setElementAt(vHulp, selectedRow);

                tmCommentaar.fireTableDataChanged();
                jtable.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

                jtable.getCellEditor(selectedRow - 1, selectedColumn).cancelCellEditing();
                jtable.changeSelection(selectedRow, selectedColumn, false, false);
                jtable.grabFocus();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

In CommentaarTableKeyListener>KeyReleased you can see what happens when push "Enter", In CommentaarTableKeyListener>KeyTyped you can see what happens when the max length is reached.  In CommentaarTableMouseListener you can see there is nothing defined for double click.

Can anyone help me?  If you have more questions, please ask.

Greetz
Sylvie

Comment: Please post SSCCE instead

Comment: I reduced it, but it's difficult for me to know how much info you need.  I hope it's enough.

Comment: _how much info you need_ the minimum that demonstrates the problem, typically around 50 lines of code :-) Read up on SSCCE for details

Comment: Now I reduced it to a minimum and stil have around 100 lines.  I can't reduce it more because in that case I delete things I'm talking about.

Comment: that's not a SSSCCE (be sure you read the article that explains what it is and why to show one). Anyway, the snippet has many issues: a) don't use keyListeners, ever b) don't fire events on hehalf of models c) assuming your mouseListener is somehow involved with editing .. that's not needed, provided your editors are well-behaved. My advise would be to take a step back and read some basic tutorial (f.i. the one referenced in the swing tag wiki)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it myself.  It had something to do with putting a string with a length of 66 characters in a fixed length textfield of 65 characters.  So problem solved!

Comment: if that seems to be a solution, then you are doing something fundamentally wrong ... text doesn't "disappear" just because it's too long.